# political assasination and rodefs

Tags: halacha, pikuachnefesh-danger-life, politics-government, murder, rodef

The classic example of a roded is a murder chasing you with a knife but sometime politicians can threaten life with bad policy.

E.g. Governor of Michigan Wants to use [Flint River](/q/68988)

Eg politician wants to defund hospital

E.g head of FDA accepts bribe to allow dangerous drug. (this happened in China and he was hanged)

E.g. Politician doesn't have any specific dangerous policies, but everyone knows he is an anti-Semite.

Do non classic rodef situations count?

Comment: Iinteresting question, but I may vote this as "opinion-based". Regardless, I think that a "rodeph" applies to an individual in the act of physically killing. I.e. someone who is known to have killed others cannot be a rodeph until he is out to kill you. Halachically, you can't just go and kill a murderer until after he has been put on trial and convicted. I doubt that any of this applies to anti-Semitic politicians, anyway. Not every anti Semite is out to kill people, & even halachically, we don't kill anyone for lashon hara or hatred.

Comment: This question has be a hot enough topic that it's [merits a section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodef#Modern_controversy) of English WP's entry for "Rodef."

Comment: @IsaacMoses This Wikipedia article impresses me as a possible example of lashon hara. Granted that it states well-known facts, but, it also seems to be a remote attempt to justify the actions, the way I see it.

Comment: I am not sure, but it seems that Rodef is a case of immediately process. 
We may consider also "הבא להרגך השכם להרגו " but I have no time to search.

Comment: Why aren't these cases of gerama?